# Vue.js: Unable to use a dropdown button inside a App Bar in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify `<v-btn>` inside a `<v-app-bar>`.

```
<template>
    <v-app-bar>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <v-btn  color="primary">
            Menu
        </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

I am trying to make this particular button a drop down menu. For that I am trying to encapsulate this button inside a `<template>` with an activator prop.

```
<template>
    <v-app-bar>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>

        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }"> 
            <v-btn  color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                Menu
            </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

But the moment I do this, the button just disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the button as an activator for a dropdown menu you have to wrap that template by `v-menu` component then add a list of items :

```
<template>
    <v-app-bar>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer
<v-menu>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
         Menu
        </v-btn>
      </template>
  <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          @click=""
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
 </v-menu>

    </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

for more details check [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/)